# Javascript XPATH Get Last Element of Repeating Child Nodes

Tags: javascript, xpath, element

I'm trying get find a way to get the last instance of an element in an XML response.  The XML contains error details which holds an object with full error details inside:

```
<error description="Anything">
    <object>
        <error description="Actual Error">
            <!-- error information in here -->
            <errorCode>123</errorCode>
            <message>Error message</message>
        </error>
    </object>
</error>
```

I always want the last 'error' and I can get the error details from the above fine with

```
error.xpath('/error/object/error').item(0).getAttribute('description');
```

followed by the subsequent details (code, message etc.)

The problem arises if the error has bubbled up through multiple exception handlers, as each one adds their own error element, so it ends up looking like this:

```
<error description="Anything">
    <object>
        <error description="Something Else">
            <object>
                <error description = "Actual Error">
                    <!-- error information in here -->
                    <errorCode>123</errorCode>
                    <message>Error message</message>
                </error>
            </object>
        </error>
    </object>
</error>
```

This repeating object-error pattern could continue more than once, depending on how many times the exception was rethrown.  To get the details from the above I would need:

```
error.xpath('/error/object/error/object/error').item(0).getAttribute('description');
```

I would never expect more than 2 or 3 rethrows but I don't want to write nasty code to try-catch at 4 different levels.

I've read about 'last()' and tried

```
(//element[@name='error'])[last()]
```

but I think I'm getting the syntax wrong as it is returning undefined.

Is there a simple way to always get the last (deepest) instance of the 'error' element inside this kind of repeating XML tree?

I only want to read the data in the XML, I don't need to translate or change anything.

Many thanks!

Comment: do you mean `(//error)[last()]` or `(//*[name()='error'])[last()]`?

Comment: @Andersson I'll be honest, I don't know the difference :(  I've tried both the above but they just throw run-time exceptions.  Is this XLST?  It doesn't seem to work no matter how I write it.

Comment: The XPath is correct. Maybe you're using it incorrectly.. Show your code

Comment: @Andersson Actually I lied - looks like `exception.xpath("(//*[name()='error'])[last()]").item(0).getAttribute('description');` is getting the deepest error description.  Just now fails when I try and get the subsequent nodes (errorCode etc.)

Comment: Show how you're trying to select `errorCode`

Comment: @Andersson I've tried `(//*[name()='error'])[last()]/errorCode` and `(//*[name()='errorCode'])[last()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML Spear to copy a X-path from an xml. That could get you started.

You can find the freeware at http://www.donkeydevelopment.com

Comment: It doesn't looks like OP need a tool to get XPath for each case, but a generic XPath applicable for each case

Comment: XML Spear can give OP an idea of how to format his Xpath in this certain case.And from there he can adapt the xpath to something generic he can use to fit every situation. i.e. the last element.

Comment: @Sparky Unfortunately our place has got a really (irritatingly) strict policy for 'approved' software and if it's not on our list I can't install it (we're monitored like Big Brother!)  Might be able to try it out on my home PC later.  I really just want to always be able to get the last 'error' element, no matter how deep within the XML it sits.

Comment: Thing is that **@name='error'** only works if the tag is **<error name="error">**. In this situation you'd use: **error[last()]**

Comment: The @ symbol is used to filter on attributes of a tag. the tag itself is just plainly the tag's element.

Comment: So if you want to read the description of that error, you'd use **error[last()]/@name**